# « Ben manque » ?

Tags: québec, adverbes, locutions, régionalismes

> — Viens-tu à la fête ce soir ? 
>  — *Ben manque* !

C'est une réponse entendue au sud ouest du Québec d'une personne qui vient de Matane (Gaspésie) et on n'a pas compris sauf *bien quelque chose*. Je n'ai pas trouvé l'expression au Larousse. [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ben_manque) dit que c'est surtout propre à la région du bas du fleuve, pour *probablement*.

---

- D'où on a pêché cette expression ?
- Qu'est-ce que le *manque* vient faire là-dedans ?
- Y a-t-il d'autres sens à l'expression ?

Comment: "Ben manque" ne se dit pas en France, du moins pas tel quel.

Comment: @Random Merci. Avant d'avoir lu l'explication, l'auriez-vous spontanément compris, si quelqu'un vous avait répondu comme dans l'exemple ? Qu'auriez-vous compris ?

Comment: Je n'aurais absolument pas compris le sens, j'aurais donc demandé de reformuler :)

Comment: Je ferais bien un parallèle avec le franco-français "Ben il ne manquerait que ça !"

Comment: @Law29 Quel parallèle ? Merci.

Comment: Le parallèle d'utiliser le verbe manquer :) *Il ne manquerait (plus) que ça* signifie que *ça* est la dernière chose qui manque pour que la situation devienne... catastrophique, ou autre qualificatif désagréable. Si j'ai bien compris, le sens serait inversé par rapport à  *Ben manque*, mais (à mon avis) le sens peut s'inverser avec le contexte, ainsi *— Viens-tu à la fête ce soir ? — Ben il ne manquerait plus que ça !* pourrait se comprendre comme *Bien sûr que non* que comme *Tu sous-entends que je ne viendrais pas, mais bien sûr que si*.

Comment: *Autant*, ou *aussi bien*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On dit que la [locution](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ben_manque) adverbiale québécoise « *ben manque* », pour **probablement/sûrement**, est surtout employée dans l'[est du Québec](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/ben-manque/), en particulier dans le [Bas St-Laurent](http://www.wikebec.org/ben-manque/definition/), en Gaspésie, ou même sur la [Côte-Nord](http://www.immigrer.com/page/outils_dictionnaire-des-expressions-quebecoises.html), voire au Lac etc. Partout sauf au sud-ouest (Montréal) faut-il croire. Au *TLFi* à *manque*, on a la locution vieillie *sans [manque](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manque)* pour « *sans faute, à coup sûr* » :

> Je suis le roi de France (je suppose), j'entends un Laffitte, un
>   Rothschild, ou tel autre gros argentier, laisser échapper le fatal
>   souhait [si j'étais riche]; je réunis vite mon conseil, j'assemble
>   autour de moi mes bonnes gardes nationales, et je me cramponne à la
>   selle; car, le cas échéant, cet homme-là en veut **sans manque** à mon
>   char royal.
>
> [ Honoré de Balzac, [*Si j'étais riche*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qLo-AAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA504&ots=p5zl7GDJw9&dq=Je%20suis%20le%20roi%20de%20France%20(je%20suppose)%2C%20j'entends%20un%20Laffitte&pg=PA504#v=onepage&q=Laffitte&f=false), ds. *Croquis et
>   fantaisies*, 1836 ]

---

Au [*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), préparé par la Société du parler français du Canada, éd. L'action sociale, 1930, à la p. 439 :

[image]

On a trois sens : *Beaucoup/volontiers, sans hésiter/probablement*. En note on parle de *vantiers* comme d'une contraction de [*volontiers*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/269675) qui a déjà voulu dire *probablement* ou *sans doute* au 16-17<sup>e</sup>. Par ailleurs on a identifié [*bien manque*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/34201) (Chateaubriant/Loire-Maritime) directement pour *il n'y a pas de doute* (FEW) mais *a contrario* (*manque* pour beaucoup... de chances, semble-t-il). Il va sans dire que l'origine diffère (*volontarius, mancus*).

Au *Bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 993 h) on dit que ça signifie « certainement » (« J'suis ben manque fâché contre toi » dans un ouvrage de Seutin, soit [ici](https://books.google.ca/books?id=I7Z4PQAACAAJ&dq) ou [là](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_dS8tgAACAAJ&dq)), on réfère à l'entrée au FEW et à sa note 14, qu'on résume par « développement sémantique obscur » (« Die semantische entwicklung ist unklar; vgl. auch piem. *manca* (prǎs. 3) „havvene in abbondanza“. » FEW).

---

**R.** Il peut s'agir de *volontiers* ou de *manque* qui se trouve derrière la   locution *b(i)en manque* dans son sens de *probablement* au Québec. Peut-être que le prototype de la locution provient de Maine, Anjou, Saintonge ou de Loire ou d'un amalgame et on ne sait pas si on l'entend en France aujourd'hui mais ça semble venir d'un de ces dialectes.

Answer (score 1):

Dans l'est du Québec, d'où je suis, "*ben manque*" est davantage l'équivalent de *probablement* que de sûrement, **sans autre sens**. Ainsi, on entend: -Il (Y) va *ben manque* neiger demain... -Si Paul serait d'accord avec nous? *Ben manque*!...

Answer (score 1):

Au Lac-Saint-Jean, l'expression "ben manque" signifie en abondance, plus qu'il n'en faut.
"Jai fait des beignes, il y en a ben manque, je vais pouvoir en donner aux voisins"

Answer (score 1):

Au Lac St-Jean ou utilise ce régionalisme bien spécial pour exprimer qu’il y en a beaucoup ou peu: “y en a ben manque” et “y en a pas ben manque”. J’ai étudié un an à Dolbeau et je me souviens très bien qu’un confrère de classe du nom de Tremblay (donc un authentique bleuet) m’avait EXPLIQUÉ la signification de cette expression que je ne connaissais pas et que je trouvais “bizarre”…  Yvon R.